# How to switch to a new "Login dialog" in browser via Selenium2Library?

Tags: authentication, robotframework, selenium2library

I have to automate a login test using RobotFramework (python-backed) and the selenium2Library.

The login page uses a Login Dialog box with two fields. I cannot seem to be able to set a RobotFramework script to get the text into the appropriate text boxes within the loginDialog however.

Any help is greatly appreciated. [image: This is what I am trying to get to.]

This is what I am working with for now. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the username and password as part of the url.

For example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library

Suite Teardown  Close all browsers
Suite Setup     Open browser  about:blank  ${BROWSER}

*** Variables ***
${BROWSER}   chrome
${USERNAME}  admin
${PASSWORD}  admin

*** Test Cases ***
Basic authorization
    go to  https://${username}:${password}@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth
    page should contain  Congratulations! You must have the proper credentials.
```